# In HTML attributes, When to use a comma, and When to use a space

Tags: html

```
<frameset cols="25%,75%"></frameset> <!-- comma -->
<input type="text" form="first second three" />  <!-- space -->
<input type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />  <!-- comma -->
<div class="a b c d">   <!-- space -->
```

so, In HTML attributes, When to use a comma, and When to use a space

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#comma-separated-tokens

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time it just comes to to learning which one to use for which element.

Essentially, you should consider comma-separation as an **AND** statement, and a space as an **OR** statement. In `<input type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />`, you want the upload to allow **both** `.gif` and `.jpeg` files. In `<div class="a b c d">`, you want the declaration to apply to **any** of the classes.

Note that `<frameset>` is deprecated in HTML5, so you should avoid using it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

There's no general rule. It depends on the html element/attribute.

Other example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```